# Using Ctools, how do I render a managed_file from system form?

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm adding some fields to Drupals site-information form. Textfields and managed_file fields. Images are uploaded there and not in my panel panes edit form.

Now I want to make the additional fields I've added, or just the whole form be rendered in a custom panel content_type. I have no issue getting the textfields themselves using

```
$block->content .= filter_xss_admin(variable_get('phonenumber', ''));
```

however I also need to render my managed_file. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not my day today :D

Here's how to do what you were asking:

```
// Load the managed file. You need this so you can get the URI.
$file = file_load(YOUR_FILE_ID);
// Generate the output.
$output = theme('image', array(
  'alt' => t('Your image alt title'),
  'title' => t('Your image human title'),
  'attributes' => array('src' => $file->uri),
));
```

Comment: You could also add the file as a required Ctools context iirc.

Comment: Where would I put this? I tried `function MYMODULE_PLUGINNAME_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $panel_args)
{
  $block = new stdClass();
  $file = file_load('phoneicon');
  $output = theme('image', array(
   'alt' => t('Alt'),
   'title' => t('Title'),
   'attributes' => array('src' => $file->uri),
  ));
  $block->content = $output;
}`

but it just returns an img tag with my normal url (example.com) as source.